# I am not able to find anaconda navigator after installing

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, prompt

I have installed anaocnda but I am not able to find navigator. I also tried using prompt to run jupyter notebook but the command could't run. Does it have something to do with the path?

Below is the message that I get every time I try to run a command

> C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\vikas>jupyter notebook
>   Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2
>
> C:\Users\vikas>python
>   'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\vikas>spyder
>   'spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\vikas>

Comment: Hi Patel, what are the commands you run? And have you checked in the explorer whether Anaconda is located at the described path?

Comment: Have you tried invoking Python from C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\ path ?
It appears you tried to start from C:\Users\vikas and not  C:\Users\vikas\Anaconda3\

Answer (score 0):

You should type 'anaconda-navigator'. That will kick off aaconda-navigator. This is installed in the bin directory under anaconda3. There is also an Anaconda-Navigator.app in the Applications folder.